# Get email and birthday from facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

How can I get the primary email from facebook if account has multiple emails registered?

I have this method for my login button:

```
private void onClickLogin() {
        session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email")).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }
```

and this method on click to get details:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this, "NULL NULL NULL NIGGA NULL!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this, buildUserInfoDisplay(user), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
```

and here is buildUserInfoDisplay method:

```
private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
    StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");
    userInfo.append(String.format("First Name: %s\n\n", user.getFirstName()));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Last Name: %s\n\n", user.getLastName()));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", user.getBirthday()));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Email1: %s\n\n", (String) user.getProperty("email")));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Email2: %s\n\n", user.getProperty("email")));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", user.getProperty("locale")));
    return userInfo.toString();
}
```

i get first and last name, and locale right, but email and birthday i don't.

not sure what i did wrong. thank you.

ANSWER:

So the answer was just to reinstall the app. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API only returns one email address in the email field, which will be the primary email. If the user has multiple emails, only the primary email is returned. If there is no primary email, or if it is not verified, the field is not returned. Note that your app must also have the email permission.

See the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user